# Does the placing of a parenthetical make any difference in terms of grammaticality?

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following is grammatically correct?

> 1. The shopping mall is not responsible for any damage to products (THAT results from customers' improper usage)
> 2. The shopping mall is not responsible for any damage (THAT results from customers' improper usage) to products

Comment: #2 is very awkward and the sentence gains nothing.  There's no chance that the listener will think the products (plural) and not the damage *is* (singular) the result of improper use, and so there's no need to reposition the that-clause.  And you could always say "product damage" instead of "damage to products".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't use parentheses for that sentence. I would say:

> The shopping mall is not responsible for any damage to products that results from customers' improper usage

That being said, inserting a parenthetical phrase in the middle of *damage to products* makes it harder to understand, in my opinion. They are both grammatically correct.

Comment: i use parentheses to highlight the position of relative clause :)

Answer (score 1):

> The shopping mall is not responsible for any **damage to products** that results from customers' improper usage.

The topic here is about customers' damaging products.

> The shopping mall is not responsible for any damage that results from customers' **improper usage** *of* products.

This could mean the same thing, but also could mean some other damage occurred. The focus here is on *improper usage*, not *damage to products*.

> The shopping mall is not responsible for any damage that results from customers' improper usage *of* products, including personal injury or property damage.